# Negate the following sentence: If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x \neq 0$, then $\text{tan}(x) \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Negate the following sentence:

If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x \neq 0$, then $\text{tan}(x) \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

I want to make sure my negation is correct. I will first convert the statement into symbolic logic.

$\textbf{Breaking apart:}$

$P = x \in \mathbb{Q}$, Q = $x \neq 0$.

$R = (P \wedge Q) $

$S = \text{tan}(x) \notin \mathbb{Q}$

$R \Rightarrow S = \hspace{1mm} \sim R \vee S$

$\textbf{Negating:}$

\begin{align} \sim(\sim R \vee S) &= (R \hspace{1mm}\wedge \sim S)\\&= ((P \wedge Q) \wedge \sim S) \\&= x\in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } x \neq 0\text{ and } \text{tan}(x) \in \mathbb{Q} \end{align}

Is my negation correct? and is it possible for the negation of a statement to be an open sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point: your answer has an "if" but no "then".  It therefore is ungrammatical, makes no sense, and cannot possibly be the right answer.

Second point: you can do this by symbolic logic if you want, but why?  IMHO it merely adds extra work.  (That's in this case: in a more complicated question it might be a good idea.)

The negation of "if $P$ then $Q$" is "$P$ and not $Q$".  In your case,

> $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $x\ne0$ and not $(\,\tan x\notin\Bbb Q\,)$

which can be simplified to

> $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $x\ne0$ and $\tan x\in\Bbb Q$.

---

**Edit**: as you have removed the "if" from your answer, it is now correct.  I still suggest that using symbolic logic is not worth the trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Just wanted to practice with Demorgan's law a bit, but I agree that writing everything out in symbolic logic is tedious.